# Executing javascript mixed with HTML from a jQuery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Or, not precisely "executing," but updating a function that exists before the response with a function returned in the response.

**Step 1**

1. I have an HTML5 page that describes a location.
2. On the server side this page includes a ColdFusion file "MapFunction.cfm."  (Which is used for consistent mapping all over the site at large.)
3. MapFunction.cfm outputs a javascript function "loadMap" mixed with the HTML.
4. loadMap() contains all the javascript needed to place a Bing map of the location on the page.
5. Some javascript in a separate js file actually calls loadMap().

This works when the page is first loaded.

**Step 2**

1. Search & results stuff is all fine too.  Nothing needs to be done with the map here.

**Step 3**

1. When a search result is clicked, the result detail is loaded asynchronously via a jQuery $.get() request.
2. It returns mixed HTML and javascript which I use jQuery to traverse through.
3. With the jQuery objects I update specific areas of the page to show different details.

One of the areas I need to update is the map.  That part isn't working.

What I'm working with is mixed HTML and Javascript that is identical in both **Step 1** and **Step 3**:

```
<section id="mod-map" class="module mod-map">
    <header class="mod-head">
        <a href="#map" class="mod-head-link"> Map <span class="arrow"></span> </a>
    </header>
    <div id="map" class="mod-body">
        <div id="cmMap" style="position:relative;width:369px;height:303px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" id="cfLoadMap">
            // ...some global variables are defined to use...
            function loadMap()
            {                   
                // ...Bing/Virtual Earth Map Stuff...
                // This part here is unique to each location's detail
                var propertypoint = new VELatLong(parseFloat(36.707756),parseFloat(-78.74204));
                // ...More Bing/Virtual Earth Map Stuff...
                // This part here is unique to each location's detail
                var label = "<div class=\"wrapper\"><img onerror=\"replaceImage(this);\" src=\"noimage.jpg\" width=\"100\" class=\"thumb\" alt=\"\" /><div class=\"caption\"><br />City<br /> State, 12345</div></div>";    
                // ...More Bing/Virtual Earth Map Stuff...              
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now, in **Step 3** loadMap() **does** get called again, but it just refreshes the map to the same location.  The loadMap() function as the browser knows it doesn't get updated with the one retrieved via ajax.

That updated block of mixed HTML & javascript above does get successfully added to the page after each ajax call.  It is placed right where it originally is, but with different coordinates and captions where indicated by the comments above.  The ajax callback looks like (slightly simplified):

```
$.get(urlToLoad, {}, function(data, status, request){   
    var newData = $(innerShiv(data, false)),
        newModules = newData.find(".module");
    // (innerShiv is used to make HTML5 tags work in IE. It's possible I'm going a little overboard with using it, but I had a lot of issues with IE. :-))
    newModules.each(function(i){
        var thisId = "#" + $(this).attr("id"),
            thisBody = $(this).find(".mod-body").html(),
            toReplaceAll = $("body").find(thisId),
            toReplaceBody = toReplaceAll.find(".mod-body");
        // These variables are used to choose add content in different ways based on thisID. Below is the one the map area is subject to.
        toReplaceBody.html(innerShiv(thisBody));                
    }); // each
    // Various things including loadMap() get called/re-initiated/etc. here
}, "html"); // get
```

This works in Firefox 3.6, but nowhere else I've tested (Opera 11, IE 7, Chrome 8).

I **have** done this before in a similar situation with dynamically PHP generated javascript written to a separate js file--$.getScript works great there.  But this is mixed into the HTML of the ajax response.

I've been looking and have found and tried the following (among other things):

**Attempted Solutions**

```
1. var myScript = new Function($('script#cfLoadMap', data).text()); myScript();
2. eval(newData.text());
3. eval(newData.find("#cfLoadMap").text());
4. $("head").append(newData.find("#cfLoadMap"));
```

None of these so far seem to be doing any good.

I know there are a few other ways this could theoretically be done.  But as it stands at the moment, I do not have any ability to change much of anything but what I do with the mixed HTML & javascript response.  I need a solution where,

- The details will be updated via ajax.
- The javascript will be mixed in with the HTML.
- The javascript will be a javascript function generated dynamically by ColdFusion.

Very similar questions have been asked & resolved before, so I hope this can be done.  However, none of the solutions I've found are working for me.  Might be making a mistake or missing something, or maybe it's just different when it's a function?

Any help would be appreciated.

### Answer

It suddenly started working with the following code:

```
$.get(urlToLoad, {}, function(data, status, request){   
    var safeData = $(innerShiv(data, false)),
        newModules = safeData.find(".module"),
        newScript = safeData.find("script#cfLoadMap");
    // Update Each module
    newModules.each(function(i){
        var jqoThis = $(this),
            thisId = "#" + jqoThis.attr("id"),
            newModule = jqoThis,
            newModBody = jqoThis.find(".mod-body"),
            curModule = $("body").find(thisId),
            curModBody = curModule.find(".mod-body");
        // Varies by id, this one is used by the map area.
        curModBody.html(innerShiv(newModBody.html()));      
    }); // each
    // Make sure plugins are bound to new content
    $("body").oneTime(100, function(){
        // Various things get initiated here
        // Maps -- this one works: Chrome, Firefox, IE7, Opera
        $("head").append(newScript);
        // Maps -- these did not work
        /* 
            // Firefox only (but Firefox always works)
            runScript = new Function(newScript.text());
            runScript();
        */
        /*
            // Firefox only (but Firefox always works)
            eval(newScript.text());
        */
    }); // oneTime
}, "html"); // get
```

One thing I *did* notice for sure was that without innerShiv, in all my browsers, $(data).find("script#cfLoadMap").text() was **blank** -- which I did *not* expect.

Comment: edited your tags so that your question can get more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly started working with the following code:

```
$.get(urlToLoad, {}, function(data, status, request){   
    var safeData = $(innerShiv(data, false)),
        newModules = safeData.find(".module"),
        newScript = safeData.find("script#cfLoadMap");
    // Update Each module
    newModules.each(function(i){
        var jqoThis = $(this),
            thisId = "#" + jqoThis.attr("id"),
            newModule = jqoThis,
            newModBody = jqoThis.find(".mod-body"),
            curModule = $("body").find(thisId),
            curModBody = curModule.find(".mod-body");
        // Varies by id, this one is used by the map area.
        curModBody.html(innerShiv(newModBody.html()));      
    }); // each
    // Make sure plugins are bound to new content
    $("body").oneTime(100, function(){
        // Various things get initiated here
        // Maps -- this one works: Chrome, Firefox, IE7, Opera
        $("head").append(newScript);
        // Maps -- these did not work
        /* 
            // Firefox only (but Firefox always works)
            runScript = new Function(newScript.text());
            runScript();
        */
        /*
            // Firefox only (but Firefox always works)
            eval(newScript.text());
        */
    }); // oneTime
}, "html"); // get
```

One thing I *did* notice for sure was that without innerShiv, in all my browsers, $(data).find("script#cfLoadMap").text() was **blank** -- which I did *not* expect.

However, I don't really see how this is different from what I had tried before and which failed.  If someone spots a substantive difference, please let me know, for future reference?

(Note: it doesn't seem to make a difference that the Map bit is placed in the timeout, it works as well above it.)

Comment: I had to do something like this again and discovered something interesting.  While working on the above I had moved the included script from just below the body to further up in HTML -- placed it in the map module.  I thought this change was incidental.  But it wasn't like that the whole time I was fighting with it. :-) And I'm discovering right now that if I don't wrap a script tag in a div (evidently it being in the body doesn't cut it), jQuery doesn't .find() it.  That's again with innerShiv--haven't tested yet to see if it's *caused* by innerShiv.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's that functions in JavaScript can be declared in non-global scope, so when you're inserting the `<script>` tag, jQuery is `eval`ing it, but not replacing the original  function (as you noticed).

A fix for this would be to change how you declare the function from this:

```
function loadMap()
{
  ...
}
```

to this:

```
window.loadMap = function loadMap() {
  ...
}
```

That way the top-level `loadMap` will always be the latest one that came down from the server.

You may want to consider not modifying the client code this way as it can make debugging trickier, but that's totally up to you. Hopefully this answer works for you either way.

Comment: Hmm, great idea.  But I don't think I can do it here, because the part of the script I can't touch has some variables declared before the function.  So I might have been able to hard code something like window.loadMap = <cfinclude ...>, but the output wouldn't be right.  It'd go window.loadMap = var map = something;, etc.  I want to try that on a mocked up version to see if it helps, though, for sake of my education if nothing else...  Thanks again :-)

Comment: There's no reason you can't have variables declared beforehand. If you want them to be global, use the same trick (`window.foo = ...`), if not just use `var`. The function will have access to them since they're in its scope. **EDIT:** Just noticed that you said there's part you can't touch. In that case I'd consider not modifying the client code and seeing what you can do with that, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I can't edit anything in "MapFunction.cfm."  Although it's actually a method in a cfc that's being called, that's the general idea. :-)  And I can't change it because it's used elsewhere--even the smallest modification I'd have to discuss, get someone else to take care of, then they'd have to test...  Anyway, it may be we can change it or add to it eventually, but right now we can't, so I've got what I've got insofar as the loadMap function is concerned.